# How to change the Cakephp Default link color?

Tags: css, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to change the color of the link in Cakephp but ut remains default color that is blue.I tried this one

```
<td <?php if ($current_date > $dateTarget) { echo "style='color:red;'"; } ?>>
```

But it make no effect.
Any Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->tag('td', null, array('style' => $current_date > $dateTarget ? 'color: red !important;' : null )); ?>
```

This is not the best solution would have to create a class in the css, like:

```
.new_link{
   color: red;
}
```